# How many four digits numbers are there not containing zero and multiplication of its digits divisible by 7?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, solution-verification, problem-solving

I saw a question in my math book, it seems very trivial, it says that:

> How many four digits numbers are there not containing zero and
> multiplication of its digits divisible by 7?

I thought of:

(all four digits numbers not containing zero) minus (all four digits numbers not containing 7 and 0)

in order to find all four digits number not containing zero and multiplication of its four digits divisible by 7.

Then $(9^4)-(8^4)=2465$. However the answer is $4904$. What am I missing?

Comment: You're solution is correct.

Comment: Yes your solution is right. Are you sure of the statement?

Comment: @Axel yes i am definitely sure. it simply says that  let A= abcd where abcd are in  the set of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.find the all A's whose multiplicaiton of digits ,i.e a*b*c*d, are divisible by 7

Comment: Well there must be a mistake somewhere. Because your answer is right, I have even checked with Python. And one can easily show that the product of $A$'s digits is divisible by $7$ iff at least one of the digit is $7$.

Comment: In fact there are $4904$ four digits numbers such that the product of their digits is divisible by 7. Maybe there is a mistake in your math book.

Comment: @Axel I guess you meant *not* divisible by 7 in your last comment?

Comment: @Manan No, why?

Comment: @Axel Isn't that precisely the claim that the math book makes- that the number of 4 digit numbers such that their product of digits is divisible by 7 is 4904? I believe the number of 4 digit numbers, not including 0 as a digit, *not* divisible by 7 is 4904.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant; so you're including all the $4$ digit numbers, even those including $0$ when you accounted $4904$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111814/discussion-between-axel-and-manan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first answer is right in regard of the statement you gave, indeed:

Let $(a,b,c,d) \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}^4$. So $A = 1000a+100b+10c+d $ is a four-digit number.

Morevover, $a\cdot b \cdot c \cdot d $ is divisible by $7$, if and only if, its prime factorization contains at least one time $7$ so, if and only if, at least one of $A$'s digit is equal to $7$. Hence the answer is $9^4-8^4 = 2465$ as you said.

**However** if you are looking for the number of four-digit numbers such that the product of their digits is divisible by $7$ the answer is $4904 = 8(10^3-8^3) + 10^3$. You can check that: in order for a four-digit number $A$ to have the product of its digits divisible by $7$, it must contain $0$ or $7$.

Let $A = 1000a+100b+10c+d$ where $0\leq a,b,c,d \leq 9$ are integers and $a \neq0$.

If $a=7$ then you can have all the combinations possible for $b,c$ and $d$. Thus, it gives you $10^3$ choices.

If $a \neq 7$, then you are looking for the number $n$ of possibilities to have at least $b,c$ or $d$ equals to $0$ or $7$. Morevover, you have exactly $8^3$ possibilities for $b$, $c$ and $d$ not to be equal to $0$ nor $7$. Hence $n = 10^3-8^3$. Finally there are only $8$ possibilities for $a$ to be different from $7$.

Therefore the number you are looking for is $8(10^3-8^3)+10^3 = 4904$.

Comment: thanks for your all effort for solving my question.However i could not comprehend what the difference is between my solution and your last one.As you mentioned, i am looking for the number of four number digits such that the product of their digits is divisible by 7 such as 1117,1567,1777 etc. I thought that this could have been found by permutation like i did.

Comment: by the way can you explain the last solution a little bit

Comment: Ok no problem. The difference is that you were looking for all four digit numbers **with no digit equals to $0$** such that the product of the digits is divisible by $7$ as you said, so for example $2457$. But if you look for every four digit number such that the product of their digits is divisible by $7$ you end up with $4094$ numbers, for example $1017, 2040, 4782$ are such numbers.

Comment: I edited my answer for you to have more explanations on how I got to $4094$.

Comment: sir thanks for your elegant explanation and efforts. You are right, i have understood it. it seems that my book is a little bit wrong because it underlines that it should not contain any zero digits.Have a good day..

Comment: @leonard you are welcome. I'm glad it helped you deal with this ambiguous exercise. Have a nice day too.